# Docker pull throwing EOF exceptions

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I recently installed Docker on my setup from https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/. When I try to pull any image in my terminal, it throws following error:

```
(base) harshgoyal@lawn-128-61-61-143 ~ % docker pull docker/getting-started
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": EOF
(base) harshgoyal@lawn-128-61-61-143 ~ %

(base) harshgoyal@lawn-128-61-61-143 ~ % docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.23
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.19.5
 Git commit:        715524332f
 Built:             Wed Jan 18 20:42:16 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.16.2 (95914)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.22
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.9
  Git commit:       42c8b31
  Built:            Thu Dec 15 22:25:43 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.14
  GitCommit:        9ba4b250366a5ddde94bb7c9d1def331423aa323
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
(base) harshgoyal@lawn-128-61-61-143 ~ %
```

System: Macbook Air M1 silicon chip with MacOS Ventura

Solutions tried:

1. Restarting docker
2. Reinstalling docker after cleaning all cache files.

Nothing has helped yet. Could someone please help me debug this issue?

Comment: In the menu bar of the the dashboard, you have a "bug" icon. Clicking on that, you'll get provided with factory reset mechanisms. Have you tried that, might be more helpful than just reinstalling. Also, have you checked, whether your machine can reach the mentioned url or tested another network?

Comment: Hi, yes I tried factory reset but that also didn't work. Yes, I tried to ping other networks and it worked fine. "ping google.com -c 5" works fine.

Comment: Directly, searching for mentioned url ("https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ ") in the web browser throws this error in Google Chrome: 
"{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to switch the network if you are facing this issue. It worked once I moved to personal hotspot. Seems my university network caused the problem.

Reference thread: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-pull-throwing-eof-exceptions/134219

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).